# What is the Double and Triple Dual of $\ell^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, dual-spaces

Suppose that we start with $c^0$ and keep taking duals,

$$c^0 \to \ell^1 \to \ell^\infty \to \ell^{\infty*} \to \ell^{\infty **} \to \ell^{\infty***} \to \ell^{\infty****}\to \dots$$

Is this an infinite sequence of distinct spaces?  If not, when does it "stabilise", i.e. stop generating new spaces?  What about other Lebesgue spaces

$$L^1(\Omega,\mu) \to L^\infty(\Omega,\mu) \to L^{\infty*}(\Omega,\mu) \to L^{\infty **}(\Omega,\mu) \to L^{\infty***}(\Omega,\mu) \to L^{\infty****}(\Omega,\mu)\to \dots?$$

I know that a Banach space is non-reflexive iff its dual is non-reflexive, but do not know anything beyond that.  Thanks!

---

Edit:

Thanks Jose for posting the mathoverflow link.  Follow-up questions:

What is the characterisation of $(L^{\infty})^{n*}, n\in\mathbb{N}$? What uses do these spaces have?

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/q/46138/149959

Comment: There is no canonical map $X\to X^*$ from a Banach space into its dual but only $X\to X^{**}$ into the bidual. You know that $X$ is reflexive if (and only if) so is $X^{**}$. This answers your question immediately.